# How can i change the size of the LVM by taking space from sd3

Tags: partitioning, ram, lvm, resize

i changed the size of the Partitoins and i gave all the free space to the sda3 partition because the lvm that I am using is located in the sda3 but the problem is that sda3 is not giving the lvm any more space so the sda3 is 20GB and the lvm is only 9GB.

I am new to UBUNTU so i am a little bitt conffused

[this is an overview with "lsblk"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn0iy.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have [webmin](https://www.webmin.com/) installed on my boxes, which allows me to control them via a GUI. With this I can expand (or shrink) an LVM via a GUI. The LVM commands are under hardware.

For command line access I refer, strangely enough, to RedHats [guides](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/logical_volume_manager_administration/lvm_overview).

One thing to note. Expanding an LV by adding space to the PV is three stage process: This is described in this [RedHat guide](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/resize-lvm-simple).

1. Expand the PV. This is done by adding partitions (on the same or a different disk) to the pv;
2. Expand the LV
3. Tell the file system to use the extra space. This is a file system command.